# thumbpdf not generating png thumbnails

Tags: thumbpdf

I have tried to use `thumbpdf` to try and generate thumbnails, working directly on the pdf file, like this:

```
thumbpdf cv.pdf
```

This has worked the first time, and produced the corresponding cv-xxx.png files, as well as a cv.tpt file. However, it hasn't worked again (even if the PDF has changed), or in a Github action environment, where it outputs this correctly:

```
THUMBPDF 3.17, 2018/09/07 - Copyright (c) 1999-2018 by Heiko Oberdiek.
*** make png files / run Ghostscript ***
!!! Warning: MediaBox not found, using default resolution: 9 DPI
Processing pages 1 through 4.
[1] [2] [3] [4]
*** make `thumbpdf.pdf' / run pdfTeX ***
*** parse `thumbpdf.pdf' ***
*** write `cv.tpt' (pdfTeX thumbnail data) ***
*** clear temp files ***
*** ready. ***
citations-year.png
cv.png
paper-citations-year-log.png
paper-citations-year-nolog.png
mv: cannot stat 'cv-0.png': No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

But it's not producing any .png file at all. I have seen there's an option `--make-png`, but it's supposed to be activated by default, so that should not be it... Any idea?

Comment: Do you *really* need `thumbpdf`? PDF previewers are able to make thumbnails on the fly, nowadays.

Comment: @egreg It's basically to create a thumbnail that can be used as icon for downloading, so yes, that's what I need...